# Am I using TextToSpeach TTS on Android properly

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SharedPreferences gameSettings = getSharedPreferences("LangPreferences",0); 
        String lang=gameSettings.getString("Lang", "");
        System.out.println("@@menu"+lang);

            setContentView(R.layout.alarm);
          toSpeak="Alarm Received weak up";
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Recieved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ttobj=new TextToSpeech(Alarm.this, 
              new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
              @Override
              public void onInit(int status) {
                 if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR){
                     ttobj.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
                    }               
                 }
              });
        //String toSpeak = write.getText().toString();
         speak();

    }
     @Override
       public void onPause(){
          if(ttobj !=null){
             ttobj.stop();
             ttobj.shutdown();
          }
          super.onPause();
       }
     public void speak()
     {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toSpeak, 
                  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               try{   ttobj.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
               }
               catch(Exception e)
               {

               }
     }
```

I am doing talking Alarm app. I written TTS in alarm class it showing alarm and toast message what i am gave to the TTS engine but TTS engine was not speaking

logcat box it showing

```
12-17 15:00:01.264: W/TextToSpeech(31970): speak failed: not bound to TTS engine
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only call speak() after onInit() was called.So better you call the speak method in onInit(). Below I modify your onInit() method.

```
       @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                ttobj.setLanguage(Locale.US); //here u have to set your local language
            }
            if(status==TextToSpeech.SUCCESS){
                speak(); 
            }
        }
```